# service stack web app AD FS authentication sample in VS2010 and .net 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, servicestack, adfs2.0

1) I am looking for AD FS2 authentication sample using service stack .net.

Unauthenticated user should be redirected to SSO page (adfs2, relay proxy) and after successful identification redirected to servicestack.net web app.

I try to start up using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT VS2012 is required.

2) What should be implemented CredentialsAuthProvider or IAuthProvider? User authenticates on SSO page.

3) I try use only razor + ss.net without MVC controllers

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that inherits from `CredentialsAuthProvider` and overrides `TryAuthenticate` method to insert your own authentication logic.

To redirect to SSO page, you can create a `Controller` class which inherits from `ServiceStackController` (`ServiceStack.Mvc` assembly) and override `LoginRedirectUrl` with something like

```
    public override string LoginRedirectUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return "~/login?redirect={0}";
        }
    }
```